# Output AWS CLI command with filters to CSV without jq

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Is there a way to output the AWS cli with filters to csv format?

For example if I wanted to take this command and output to csv:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owner self   --query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId,"Virtualization Type":VirtualizationType}'
```

How would I do that? Normally I would use jq to output the aws cli to csv. But in this case I was able to get to the info I wanted easier with the filter option instead of jq.

This is the full command I want to output to CSV:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owner self   --query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId,"Virtualization Type":VirtualizationType,Architechture:Architecture,Hypervisor:Hypervisor,State:State,ImageID:ImageId,"Device Names":BlockDeviceMappings[].DeviceName,"Snapshot IDs":BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.SnapshotId,"Delete On Termination":BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.DeleteOnTermination,"Voluem Type":BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeType,"Volume Size":BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeSize,Encrypted:BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.Encrypted,"Image Location":ImageLocation,"Root Device Type":RootDeviceType,"Owner ID":OwnerId,"Creation Date":CreationDate,Public:Public,"Image Type":ImageType,Name:Name}'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution I can think of is to output in text `--output text` and then replace the spaces with a comma:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owner self   --query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId,"Virtualization Type":VirtualizationType}' --output text
```

Output

```
ami-1234567890    hvm
ami-1a2b3c4d5e    hvm
ami-9876543210    hvm
```

Replace the blanks with a comma. There are many ways to do this using `sed` or `tr` or `awk` or `paste`.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owner self   --query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId,"Virtualization Type":VirtualizationType}' --output text | sed -E 's/\s+/,/g'
```

Output

```
ami-1234567890,hvm
ami-1a2b3c4d5e,hvm
ami-9876543210,hvm
```

Comment: This will output incorrect csv if a column value has a space in it. For example `aws --region us-east-1 ec2 describe-instance-types --query 'InstanceTypes[?GpuInfo.Gpus!=null].[InstanceType, GpuInfo.Gpus[0].Count,  GpuInfo.Gpus[0].Manufacturer, GpuInfo.Gpus[0].MemoryInfo.SizeInMiB, GpuInfo.Gpus[0].Name]' --output text` outputs 

```bash

g5.4xlarge 1 NVIDIA 24576 A10G
...
g4ad.8xlarge 2 AMD 8192 Radeon Pro V520
g4ad.4xlarge 1 AMD 8192 Radeon Pro V520

```

Your script would output `g4ad.4xlarge,1,AMD,8192,Radeon,Pro,V520` instead of `g4ad.4xlarge,1,AMD,8192,Radeon Pro V520`

Comment: @Anshul I agree but the question was for AMI and Virtualization Type which do not have space in them. You can easily to refine the command to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 6):

We had to do something very similar today and we used jq to get the csv output natively.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'foo' | \
  jq -r '.[][] | @csv'
```

- Note: the `.[][]` notation was required for us because our query was reformatting the output in a specific way.  I would NOT expect most cases will require referencing the output in the same way.
- Note 2: I don't recall the original question saying "without jq", so while my cli works, I now realize it does not meet the OP goal.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the command to reflect that.

Comment: Perfect, I'll remove the comment as it might be confusing otherwise.